# Android ListView list:selecter is not woking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to android and my an using list view, I want to change list item color on selection but it is not working.

I have check almost all links on stack overflow and tried them all but no luck... Please check my code ... and tell me where is the problem.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private String[] menuArray;
    private List<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        menuArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Menu);
        menuList = Arrays.asList(menuArray);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_main_menu);
        listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this,menuList));       
    }

/******************************** EfficientAdapter ************************************/

    public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private String TAG=EfficientAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Context context;

        private List<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context,List<String> data) {
            super();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context=context;
            this.data.addAll(data);
        }


        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context=context;
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, null);              
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mainlist_item);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.textLine.setText(getItem(position));

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView textLine;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my xml file with list view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Gainsboro"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_main_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/DarkGray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/row_color"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_color.xml**

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@color/Green" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/Blue" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/Brown" />

<item 
    android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/Cyan" />
```

**main_list.xml; this xml contain textview which is inflating**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_mainlist_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkSlateGray"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:text=">"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkSlateGray"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Just found that only this portion is working fine**

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/Green" />
```

Comment: I just put a potential issue with your code. But where are you trying to change the items color? Would be nice to tell us exactly where that is :)

Comment: i have edited my question and added xml file code. i have also made the change you suggested in answer but nothing happened. I want to change list item color, see this code line android:listSelector="@drawable/row_color"

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of a single item so they are unique, have them be the same color, or have the actual list itself have that color drawable?

Comment: I want to change the color of List Item only if it is clicked/selected. For example if i have a list of countries and when i select Japan it should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html

Hope it works for you

Comment: add android:background="@drawable/row_color" in main_list.xml on frame layout and remove from list view.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, null);
```

Try

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, parent, false);
```

**EDIT**:

I see what you are trying to do now. You don't want to have `android:ListSelector` on ListView, but rather on each individual `FrameLayout`. So:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/row_color" >
```

You would need to apply it to each individual view in order to have them change color when pressed, etc.